# How to set agents hight in delay block?

Tags: anylogic

By seizeTransporter block my AGV seizes an agent called "Sitz" and transports it via Move by Transporter block to a Delay Block.

When AGV enters the delay block the transported agent "Sitz" is changing its cargo location to 0.

I tried to fix that issue with creating an parameter on main called p_assemblyHight with default value 1.0 and the following code in Actions section of the delay Block: agent.setHight(p_assemblyHight, METER);

Anyway this action will not execute.
What can I do so that my transported product (called "Sitz") stays on the agv and not dropping in delay block?

Check the two screenshots for better understanding.
Thank you a lot!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `setHeight` method does not change the z-component, but the height of an agent presentation. Irrelevant for you.

You need to access your `Sitz` in the delay block and change its z-component.

In the Delay block call:

```
agent.setXYZ(agent.getX(), agent.getY(), 10);
```

The last argument is the Z component, adjust as needed. The first 2 just make sure the XY components are not changed

Comment: Thanks for your fast response Benjamin! I´m not sure what you mean by "variable mySitz (storing the Sitz it carries)". My AGV has a variable which I called "v_assemblyHight" (integer with initial value 1). So the call in the `Delay` block would be `agent.v_assemblyHight.setXYZ...`? Then, the error "Cannot invoke getY() on the primitive type int"

Comment: If your AGV transports "Sitz" agents, it must somehow know about them. There are a million ways how you set this up, mine was just a common approach. Clarify the detailed setup of how AGVs and Sitz agents know about each other (in your original question, you should be able to edit it).

Comment: Ok, I added some further information about the connection between AGV and Sitz. Let me know if that suits you. Thank you again for your effort!

Comment: From your first screenshot, your "Sitz" agent is the one moving through your flowcharts, so agent.setXYZ(agent.getX(), agent.getY(), 10) should work just fine. Otherwise, if you want to do it through your transporters' functions, you can use setCargoPosition().

Comment: Reply adjusted :)

Comment: Unfortunately, your command is still not executed. I checked everything several times now. I can't find the reason ...

Comment: From your pics, it is the AGV Z component not working, right? But it is Sitz agents moving through the blocks, no wonder it is not working. You need to clarify how Sitz and AGV "know" about each other. Is one embedded in the other? Is there a variable in Sitz `myAGV`?

Comment: No the Sitz Z component does not work. Sitz has to remain on AGV no matter what block they are in. There is no direct connection between Sitz and AGV. Neither embeded nor variable in Sitz. All I have done was creating a flow chart where AGV drives to Node `loadingPoint` via seizeTransporter block. AGV is waiting at this Node until a crane places Sitz at the same Node. Because of the previously mentioned seizeTransporter block the crane places Sitz right on AGV. A following moveByTransporter block transports AGV (with Sitz on it) to the delay block.

Comment: try the `setCargoPosition()`  as suggested above...?